# Диапазонное регулярное выражение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Что то голову сломал. Нужно вырезать все числа в диапазонах от 45...250 и 450...2500 из строки. Помогите с регулярным выражением. В строке помимо цифр еще может быть и текст.

Comment: Пример конкретный отобразите.

Comment: какой то текст 50 и еще текст 2000
тест 2400 
и т.п. 

нужно цифры срезать в этих диапазонах

Comment: Готова регулярка в комплекте с проверочной программой :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего лишнего:

```
<?php

$string = '45 Нужно вырезать все числа от 45...250 и 450...2500 из строки, и оставить числа вида 2100100 45';
//Нужно вырезать все числа от ... и ... из строки, и оставить числа вида 2100100

echo preg_replace_callback('~(?<=\D|\b)\d{2,4}(?=\D|\b)~', function ($a) {
    $a = $a[0];
    return ($a >= 45 && $a <= 250) || ($a >= 450 && $a <= 2500) ? false : $a;
}, $string);
```

Comment: Вместо `{2,4}` надо поставить `+`, иначе более длинные будут вытаскиваться частями: `2100100` => 2100, 100.

Comment: @Qwertiy, та же фигня в ответе hardworm.

Comment: @Qwertiy подправил свой пример. Спасибо.

Comment: @Эдуард, да, тоже вариант. Почти. Есть косяк с `(?<=\D)` - если строка начинается с числа, то эта штука не найдёт символ. И аналогично с числом в конце.

Comment: @Qwertiy вот как... Ну, тогда завтра подправлю шаблон. Спасибо.

Comment: @Qwertiy добавил в шаблон пару альтернатив, вроде бы всё ок.

Comment: @Эдуард, да, нормально.

Answer (score 5):

Вместо возможного, но монструозного регулярного выражения на тему, лучше воспользуйтесь [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$text = "какой 10 то текст 50 и еще текст 2000 тест 2400 и 4000 ещё";

$res = preg_replace_callback("/\d+/", function($match){
  $num = +$match[0];

  if(($num > 45 && $num < 250) || ($num > 450 && $num < 2500)){
    return '';
  }

  return $num; // какой 10 то текст  и еще текст  тест  и 4000 ещё
}, $text);

print $res;
```

https://repl.it/KoV6/0

Answer (score 3):

> 45...250

Делим на куски 45..49, 50..99, 100..199, 200..249, 250 и собираем:

```
4[5-9]|[5-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|250
```

> 450...2500

Можно сделать аналогично, но не нужно :)

> 45...250 и 450...2500

Просто добавим необязательные последние цифры к прошлому выражению:

```
4[5-9][0-9]?|[5-9][0-9][0-9]?|1[0-9][0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9][0-9]?|2500?
```

> Нужно вырезать все числа в диапазонах

Чтобы не было ложных срабатываний, надо потребовать, чтобы по краям были не цифры:

```
(?<!\d)(?:тут-само-выражение)(?!\d)
```

Итого:

```
(?<!\d)(?:4[5-9][0-9]?|[5-9][0-9][0-9]?|1[0-9][0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9][0-9]?|2500?)(?!\d)
```

## Проверка: https://ideone.com/ZihNRV

```
$text = "";

for ($q=1; $q<3002; ++$q)
  $text .= "$q ${q}0 ${q}1 1$q 1${q}1 ";

$pattern = '/(?<!\\d)(?:4[5-9][0-9]?|[5-9][0-9][0-9]?|1[0-9][0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9][0-9]?|2500?)(?!\\d)/';

preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);

$vals = $matches[0];

foreach ($vals as $val)
  if ($val < 45 || $val > 250 && $val < 450 || $val > 2500)
    echo $val . " - FAIL\n";

sort($vals);
$found = preg_replace('/(?<!\\d)(\\d+)( \\1)+/', '$1', join(' ', $vals));

$key = '45';

for ($q=46; $q<=250; ++$q)
  $key .= ' ' . $q;

for ($q=450; $q<=2500; ++$q)
  $key .= ' ' . $q;

echo $found === $key ? "All numbers found :)\n" : "Something went wrong!!!\n";

echo $found;
```

Comment: Да, все правильно https://regex101.com/r/dX6BuB/2 это для первого диапазона.

Comment: @ПашаИванов, ага, см. обновление.

Comment: Кажется кто-то излишне заморочился.

Comment: @Skyrocker, мне тоже так кажется... А можно плюсик?)

Answer (score 1):

Используй preg_replace_callback http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php

```
$string = 'test100-bigtest2000ANd###9999999';

function checkNumber($matches)
{
    if($matches[0] >= 45 && $matches[0] <=250) {
        return '';
    }
    if($matches[0] >= 450 && $matches[0] <=2500) {
        return '';
    }
    return $matches[0];
}

echo preg_replace_callback('/\d{2,4}/u', 'checkNumber', $string);
```